# How to Test the Ecommerce Transaction?

Tags: testing, google-analytics, e-commerce

Is it possible to test whether the Google Ecommerce transaction code is working or not before It is send to production?

Comment: this link might help you...http://www.ppchero.com/our-guide-to-google-analytics-iq-testing-e-commerce-tracking/

Answer (score 0):

Most merchant service providers have a test mode setting. See if you find that. Also you can place real transaction and just refund them after you complete.